# Use powershell to remove last row in .csv file

Tags: powershell, csv, scripting

I am currently in need of a solution for one of our automation scripts. As part of the process it grabs the file from a source and it has to remove last row in the .csv and save it again as csv file(not sure why this has to be done, as file already comes as .csv, but without it - it bugs out). The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to remove the last row. I came up with few solutions but most only work on .txt file or objects. What I have now is this:

```
Import-Csv $file | where {$_.'Search Status' -ne "Blank line"} | Export-Csv "\file.csv" -notypeinfo
```

It does delete the last line that has ' Blank Line' written in it, but it seems to just remove the text and when my other script parses the file it fails to do so properly. So to sum up - I need a script that would take this file, remove last row completely and save it again as .csv as 'export-csv' doesn't seem to do the job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In **PSv5+** you can use `Select-Object`'s `-SkipLast` parameter:

```
Get-Content $file | Select-Object -SkipLast 1 | Set-Content out.csv -Encoding UTF8
```

Note that I'm simply using `Get-Content` rather than `Import-Csv`, as there's no good reason to incur the overhead of `Import-Csv` (construction of a custom object for each input line) and subsequent `Export-Csv` (serialization of each custom object to a comma-separated list of values in a single string) if the only task required is to *drop a line* as a whole.

Also note that I've included an `-Encoding` argument to illustrate the point that you may want to control the output encoding explicitly, because the input encoding is never preserved in PowerShell.
`Set-Content` will default to "ANSI" encoding on Windows PowerShell, and BOM-less UTF-8 on PowerShell Core.

---

In **PSv4-**, you can employ the following technique to emulate `-SkipLast 1`;  it allows you to do the same in a single pass too, and without needing to load the entire input file into memory:

```
Get-Content $file | ForEach-Object { $prev = $null } {      
  if ($null -ne $prev) { $prev }
  $prev = $_
} | Set-Content out.csv -Encoding UTF8
```

The above simply delays the output of the pipeline input object by one iteration, which effectively omits the *last* input object.

Comment: Huh. `-SkipLast` has no documentation (even if it is obvious by the parameter name).

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: Good point: it isn't _described_, but it is _listed_ (as part of the syntax diagram in the v6 docs; in the v5.1 and v5.0 documents, it also has a parameter-details paragraph in the body, but still lacks a description); see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/2716

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1, I made PR for that and now `-SkipLast` description is live (still yet to be merged for v5). Just FYI

Answer (score 1):

- Import the csv
- get the item count
- Select the first (count - 1) Rows
- export

---

```
$FileIn = '.\file.csv'
$FileOut= '.\file2.csv'
$csv = Import-Csv $FileIn
$csv | Select-Object -First ($csv.count -1) |
    Export-Csv $FileOut  -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

or do

```
$x = @(Get-Content -Path $file)
($x[0..($x.Length - 2)]) | Out-File -FilePath $file
```

to save from doing the `[array]::Reverse()` twice

Answer (score 0):

You can load the file into an object, remove the last line, and then re-write it:

```
$f = @(Get-Content -Path $file)
[array]::Reverse($f)
$f = $f | Select-Object -Skip 1
[array]::Reverse($f)
$f | Out-File -FilePath $file
```

Note: this is extremely lazy (and performs poorly) on my part because I didn't spend more time thinking about it, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

depending on your version of powershell you can just use the skiplast parameter of Select-Object

```
Import-Csv $file | where {$_.'Search Status' -ne "Blank line"} | select -skiplast 1 | Export-Csv "\file.csv" -notypeinfo
```

Answer (score 0):

We had some additional requirements, such as being able to check several files in a folder and making sure that the number of columns in the first row matches the number of columns in the last row. Sometimes files for us break during transfer and leave a final incomplete row in the file. Posting our solution here in case it may help someone else:

```
$path = "."
$enc = "utf8" # file encoding
$delim = '\t' # column separator, tab in this example
$terminator = "`n" # LF (unix style row terminators)
$pattern = "^.*Example\.txt$"
# ----===================================================================================----
$files = @(Get-ChildItem FileSystem::"$path" | Where-Object {$_.Name -match $pattern})
ForEach ($file in $files) {
    $filename = $file.FullName
    # count number of columns in the first row and then compare with last row
    $head_count = ((Get-Content $filename -Head 1) -split $delim).Count
    $tail_count = ((Get-Content $filename -Tail 1) -split $delim).Count
    If($head_count -ne $tail_count) {
        Write-Output "MODIFYING: $filename ($head_count head and $tail_count tail columns)"
        Copy-Item $filename -Destination "$filename.original"
        (Get-Content "$filename.original" | Select -SkipLast 1) -join $terminator | Out-File -NoNewline -Encoding $enc $filename
    }
    Else {
        Write-Output "NO ACTION: $filename ($head_count head and $tail_count tail columns)"
    }
}
```